# Check form input length via PHP with maxlength tag

Tags: php, forms, input, maxlength

My question is very simple: if I have some input fields with maxlength tag in a HTML form, I have to check input length via PHP too?

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick replies, I agree with you and I will check input length via PHP too :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should , because anyone can "duplicate" your form and use it.
Server-side checks are better than client-side. (It's safe)

For instance , your form:

```
<form method='post' action='/pay.php'>
<input type='text' maxlength='10' name='addres'>
</form>
```

I can easily do something like this: (and upload it to some free server or something like that)

```
<form method='post' action='http://www.yourdomain.com/pay.php'>
<input type='text' name='addres'><!--no maxlength='10' for me-->
</form>
```

Now I'm kind of "over pass" your limitation.

However , you can edit your `pay.php` file:

```
$addres = clean_input($_POST['addres']); //A custom function to make sure it's a clean string
if(strlen($addres) > 100)
{
  //Something weird
}
else
{
  //We're good
}
```